# Color Code Due Date for All Tasks?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, tasks

I am trying to format a Tasks list in SharePoint 2010 using Sharepoint Designer using the following settings under conditional formatting.

```
Field > Due Date = Less Than > Value = Current Date
Field > Status = Not Equal > Value = Completed
Click on Set Style > Change Text color to Red
```

When this is done some of the tasks that have dates in the future are showing in RED - this should only happen for dates that have past with tasks that are either 'In Progress', 'Waiting on someone else' or 'Not Started'.

Any ideas, anyone? :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:
http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/10/21/progress-bar-color-coding/

The solution was for 2007 but it works fine in my 2010. Of course test this on your development server.

Basically:
Create a view with: a calculated that spits out html (specified in a way to not conflict with sharepoint html)
Place view on page.
On page at footer add web part or alter page with designer (preferred in 2010 because the content editor web part actually breaks the links to choose different views.) have javascript that rerenders that html for browser viewing. Works very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Using Designer,

- open the Task list and then the View you want to format.
- Put your mouse in a cell of the column or row you want to format.
- Select "Conditional Formatting". Let me know if that helps -